# How to install `org.eclipse.update.ui` in Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-kepler

It is said in note that:

> Action required: Clients that rely on the provisional API or
>   implementation in these bundles should migrate to the functionality
>   and API provided by Equinox p2. Alternatively, products can install
>   these bundles from the Eclipse 3.8 repository and they will continue
>   to function in Eclipse 4.2-based applications.

The question is: how to accomplish that? I have added Indigo repository to `Install Software` list, but software is identified by human friendly names. How to find bundles there?

```
org.eclipse.update.core
org.eclipse.update.core.win32
org.eclipse.update.scheduler
org.eclipse.update.ui
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy required jar files from `plugin` directory of eclipse 3.8 installation to your current eclipse installation `plugin` directory:
http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/